# Java HashSet<String>'s contains() does't match after eclipse hot republish

Tags: java, eclipse

when I modify the code, eclipse will republish web application with jetty.than a problem occurred. Hashset.contains() with same String return false!

code:

```
private static HashSet<String> code = new HashSet<String>();
public String f1(){ 
    String a = getCode();
    code.add(a);
    return a; //return to webclient(Browser).
}
public void f2(String b){
    //b is read from Browser, same as a
    code.contains(b)
    // it return false! after hot reepublish
    ...
}
```

The function getEntry of HashMap return null in debug,it look likes Entry e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)]; e is null.

so, how it happend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think code is a static variable, which will be initialized when the class is load by the classloader, so when you republish your app, the code will be reset. You'd better re-add the items into the code map.